# Dynamic define the inList constraint using database query

Tags: grails, groovy

I´m trying implement something like this but an error is raising:

PersonController.Groovy

```
class PersonController
{
    static scaffold = Person
}
```

Person.groovy

```
class Person
{
    String function

    static constraints = {
        function  (inList:[Function.findAllByType("JENKIN")])
    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
...
Caused By: Method on class [com.test.domain.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
...
```

Is possible to use findBy methods inside inList constraint?

Thanks

Comment: Is your app working without setting that constraint?

Comment: You may try to use with [`validator`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)