# Grails dynamic "inList"

Tags: grails, grails3

This is almost identical to this old question: [Dynamic define the inList constraint using database query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598532/dynamic-define-the-inlist-constraint-using-database-query) which was essentially unaddressed, perhaps there have been advances in the years since that was asked.

I'd like to populate the `inList` parameter of a domain attribute with values from another domain.  Due to auto-generated views (scaffolding, filterpane), this needs to come from `inList` rather than a custom validator.

```
class MyDomain {
  String someValue
  static constraints = {
    someValue(nullable: true, maxSize: 50, inList: SomeOtherDomain.list()*.name)
  }
}
```

This gives the following error on startup:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [thepackage.SomeOtherDomain] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.`

I know, the "correct" way to handle this is to make `someValue` an instance of `SomeOtherDomain` instead of just storing the name, but that doesn't quite fit.  We want to be able to delete an instance of `SomeOtherDomain` without breaking the saved value of the owning domain...  the domain with the deleted value will be invalid going forward, and would have to be updated before saving, but archived/locked records will still exist and can be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify value lists for filterpane like this:

```
<filterpane:filterPane domain="MyObject" filterPropertyValues="${['someValue':[values: SomeOtherDomain.list().collect{it.name}]]}" />
```

And then just use a custom validator to actually validate.  I'm not sure what scaffolding might use the inList but easy enough to get around that if you're OK with replacing a few scaffolded pages with static ones.